# How completely protect/block branch in Azure Devops from Pull requests

Tags: azure-devops, azure-repos

I found how to block/protect branch from pushes, force pushes but how to protect branch from pull requests? When somebody creates pull requests branch merges with branch which locked (f.e. master branch) without any problems or acknowledges. How to protect branch from pull request Of course if it possible?

Branch lock (protect branch from pushes);
Branch security (deny force pushes)

I want to make impossible to complete pull request to locked branch. Of course if it possible.

Answer (score 3):

Plainly block branch from any PR isn't possible as a singular feature. But you can use branch policies to achieve something alike.

[ADO docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops) says you can set policies:

- Add specific person as required approver (it can be you)
- Require minimum number of reviewers (you can add 999 person)
- Check for linked work items
- Require approval from external services (via API)

Plain locking branch forever and whatever happens is not the best approach (you want to have opportunity to do that sometimes). Hope that helps.

Comment: Branch Locking does not stops users from committing to branch. And yes, nice trick, But as of today it says, `Minimum reviewers must be at least 1, and no more than 10`.

Answer (score 3):

I tested locking a branch, the result of the test is that it can successfully prevent other users from completing the pull request and merge to the target branch.

When I lock the master branch, and then create pr from the dev branch to the master branch, when I click complete, I will be prompted to stop me from completing the pr.
[image]

In addition, locking the branch can also prevent me from committing to the locked branch.
[image]

So I think locking branch can meet your need.For details ,please refer to this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/lock-branches?view=azure-devops).

Comment: I can confirm this, we just tried it and it works like described in this comment

Answer (score 1):

Hm strange. Because in our case lock not preventing from PR.

Probably it depends on who made PR. His privileges in Project but I'm not sure...
[master branch lock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viXRg.png)

[successfull PR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALiD5.png)

Comment: After testing, it should be that only the person who locked the branch can successfully complete the pr merged into this brach, and others should not be able to complete the pr even if they are given the administer permission.